# Is it possible to determine if my app was started with Google Assistant?

Tags: android, android-intent

Google Assistant can start my app if i say "Open MYAPP". Is it possible to determine inside my app that it was launched this way or by tapping on it in the launcher?

I tried getting some info in `onStart()`, but i can see that its different if i launch by hand or voice, but its not in a definite way:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()
```

If i start by hand i have these key in the extras: intent_extra_launch_event and profile. If i start by voice, these two are not there.

Comment: This code show how to track source in GA, but maybe it would help you: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/deeplink-referrer/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5

Comment: thanks, but sadly it says null for both starting by voice and by hand :(